# Is there any way to check whether input n is less than or equal to length of list?

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog, I wish to get a function:
 drop(N, X, Y) that prints list Y which is the list X with its Nth element removed. If X does not have an Nth element then the predicate should fail.
Example:
1)drop(2,[1,2,3,4,5,6],Y) should give Y=[1,3,4,5,6].

2)drop(8,[1,2,3,4,5,6],Y) should fail.

I tried to get a function that appends an element of X to Y if it is not an Nth element and skips the element if it is an Nth element. Please see the following code:

```
drop(N,X,Y) :- integer(N),N>0,drop(X,1,N,Y).
drop([], _ , _ , [] ) .
drop( [X1|X] , P , N , [X1|Y] ) :- N=\=P , P1 is P+1 , drop(X,P1,N,Y) .
drop( [_|X] , P , N ,Y) :- N =:= P , P1 is P+1 , drop(X,P1,N,Y) .
```

The problem arises if N is greater than the length of the list, my code will print the entire list, but the function is supposed to fail in this case. I am not able to find a way to compare N with the length of the list since every function in prolog returns a binary value(according to my knowledge).
Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite close. There are two things that you should change here:

1. once we have reached the correct index, we should no longer recurse on `drop` but just return the rest of the list; and
2. you should remove the `drop([], _, _, [])` line, since given we dropped an element, we will no longer recurse (see previous point).

Note that we can each time decrement the value for `N` and thus prevent using two variables. Like:

```
drop(N, X, Y) :-
    integer(N),
    drop_(N, X, Y).

drop_(1, [_|T], T).
drop_(N, [X|T], [X|T2]) :-
    N > 1,
    N1 is N-1,
    drop_(N1, T, T2).
```

Comment: It means a lot to me, Thank you very much!